# type deduction from char array to std::string

Tags: c++, string, variadic-templates

I'm trying to write `sum` function using variadic template.
In the code I would write something like

```
sum(1, 2., 3)
```

and it will return most general type of the sum (in this case - `double`).
The problem is with characters. When I call it like

```
sum("Hello", " ", "World!")
```

template parameters are deduces as `const char [7]` for example, thus it won't compile. I found the way to specify last argument as `std::string("World!")`, but it's not pretty, is there any way to achieve automatic type deduction to `std::string` or correctly overload `sum`?

The code I have so far:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
auto sum(const T1& t1, const T2& t2) {
    return t1 + t2;
}

template<typename T1, typename... T2>
auto sum(const T1& t1, const T2&... t2) {
    return t1 + sum(t2...);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    auto s1 = sum(1, 2, 3);
    std::cout << typeid(s1).name() << " " << s1 << std::endl;

    auto s2 = sum(1, 2.0, 3);
    std::cout << typeid(s2).name() << " " << s2 << std::endl;

    auto s3 = sum("Hello", " ", std::string("World!"));
    std::cout << typeid(s3).name() << " " << s3 << std::endl;

    /* Won't compile! */
    /*
    auto s4 = sum("Hello", " ", "World!");
    std::cout << typeid(s4).name() << " " << s4 << std::endl;
    */

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
i 6
d 6
Ss Hello World!
```

Comment: You are using C++14, so `"World!"s`.

Comment: @T.C. I've tried this on [ideone](http://ideone.com/3fRo0M), but I've got a compilation error, am I doing it wrong?

Comment: You need a `using namespace std::literals;`.

Comment: @NikolayKondratyev it's working on my  system with `gcc (Ubuntu 4.9.2-10ubuntu13) 4.9.2` only we need to pass `-std=c++1y` flag to compile .

Comment: @T.C. Works great, thanks! I will learn more about string literals for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just write a simple overloaded identity function which handles `const char*` specially.

```
template<typename T>
decltype(auto) fix(T&& val)
{
    return std::forward<T>(val);
} 

auto fix(char const* str)
{
    return std::string(str);
}

template<typename T1, typename T2>
auto sum(const T1& t1, const T2& t2) {
    return fix(t1) + t2;
}

template<typename T1, typename... T2>
auto sum(const T1& t1, const T2&... t2) {
    return t1 + sum(t2...);
}
```

Comment: Is there any need for ``decltype``? I tried to run your solution without it and looks like it works fine.

Comment: @NikolayKondratyev: Yes, it should work fine without decltype for pretty much all situations. The decltype just makes sure that the object which is passed in is perfectly forwarded to the return type. This might be important to you if, for example, you have an unbounded integer type which does dynamic allocation, and you want to avoid the potentially expensive copy that would occur without `decltype(auto)`. Or if you have a type which is non-copyable (but still movable).

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately you're `char` pointer types don't deal well with being on both the left *and* right side of `operator +`.` You can overload to manufacture an intermediary if desired.

Below I took liberty to refactor this down to a single-param-supported `sum` (not a required step, but allows `sum(x)` overloads, which are clearer to understand). Hopefully you get the idea.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// generic identity
template<typename T1>
auto sum(const T1& t1)
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
    return t1;
}

// specialized for const char [N]
auto sum(const char *s)
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
    return std::string(s);
}

template<typename T1, typename... T2>
auto sum(const T1& t1, const T2&... t2)
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
    return t1 + sum(t2...);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    std::cout << sum(1,2,3) << '\n';
    std::cout << sum(1, 2.0, 3) << '\n';
    std::cout << sum("Hello", " ", std::string("World!")) << '\n';
    std::cout << sum("Hello", " ", "World!");
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
auto sum(const T1 &, const T2 &...) [T1 = int, T2 = <int, int>]
auto sum(const T1 &, const T2 &...) [T1 = int, T2 = <int>]
auto sum(const T1 &) [T1 = int]
6
auto sum(const T1 &, const T2 &...) [T1 = int, T2 = <double, int>]
auto sum(const T1 &, const T2 &...) [T1 = double, T2 = <int>]
auto sum(const T1 &) [T1 = int]
6
auto sum(const T1 &, const T2 &...) [T1 = char [6], T2 = <char [2], std::__1::basic_string<char>>]
auto sum(const T1 &, const T2 &...) [T1 = char [2], T2 = <std::__1::basic_string<char>>]
auto sum(const T1 &) [T1 = std::__1::basic_string<char>]
Hello World!
auto sum(const T1 &, const T2 &...) [T1 = char [6], T2 = <char [2], char [7]>]
auto sum(const T1 &, const T2 &...) [T1 = char [2], T2 = <char [7]>]
auto sum(const char *)
Hello World!
```

Best of luck